# Google Authentication Correlation failed.(Unknown location)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to add Google Authentication to Cookie Authentication with this config:
StartUp:

```
//ConfigureServices:
services.AddAuthentication( )
                    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                    {
                     //   ... 
                    })
                    .AddGoogle(options =>
                    {
                        IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                            Configuration.GetSection("ExternalLogin:Google");
                         
                        options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                        options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];  
                        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                    });

    //Configure():
         app.UseAuthentication();
         app.UseAuthorization();
```

and

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult SigninGoogle(string returnurl)
        {
            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {   RedirectUri =   Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback","Auth",new{returnurl}).ToString(),
                Items =
                {
                    { "LoginProvider", "Google" },
                },
                AllowRefresh = true,
            };
 
            return Challenge(authProperties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme );
        }



             [AllowAnonymous][HttpGet("signin-google")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnurl, string remoteError = null)
            {
                var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {}
    
    //..
}
```

after click "SigninGoogle" and login in to google it is ok!

but in back google to "signin-google" i have problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by remove CookiePolicy Middleware.

This error was caused by:

> ".AspNetCore.Correlation.XXXXX' cookie not found.

and

> options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;

override by CookiePolicy Middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Not the actual answer to your question, but bonus tip looking at your code. You can add query string parameter `provider`. This way your external login can be reusable, for instance, if you decide to add a facebook login in your program later on:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string returnUrl, string provider)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties 
        { 
            RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalResponse), 
                                     new { returnUrl, provider }) 
        };

        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalResponse(string returnUrl, string provider)
    {
        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //succeeded
        }
        else
        {
           //failed
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you
do you have any idea for solve problem?

Comment: Once in a while I was facing the same issue. I do not remember how I solved it, but try to run your program on a different browser.

Comment: i test with Firefox and chrome. same error in both

Comment: There could be numerous reasons behind this problem. I suggest you using my code snippet, plus leaving `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` options only in your configurations. Did you modify date and time settings in your OS recenly?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem ,I find that I added a few columns to my user table which weren't nullable and prevent user from registering user