# Corelation fail while setting Signin with google in ASP.NET Core 7 Blazor server app

Tags: google-oauth, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-7.0

I am trying to configure signin and signup using google in my Blazor server app using ASP.NET Core 7 and when I click on login and after that It ask me for the select the account when I click on that I shows me this error.

This is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

In ASP.NET Core 7 Blazor server app - here is the code of my `program.cs` file

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(Options =>
{
    var clientid = builder.Configuration["Google: ClientId"];
    Options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientId"];
    Options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Google:Clientsecret"];
    Options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:profile", "link");
    Options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:image", "picture");
});

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();
// Required for Httpclient
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
```

Here is the reference link from where I am doing this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/830958/how-to-implement-google-authetication-in-blazor-se

I can't understand the error

Comment: maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/q/66744435/1841839